# wamp local server, blank page returned after submitting button

Tags: input, wamp

Input code:

```
<form method="post" action="input.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <tr align="center">  
          <td><input required="required" type="text" class="inp" name="nume" size="30" style="text-align: center" placeholder="Introdu aici numele t&#259;u">
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr align="center">
          <td><br /><br /><font face ="Impact" size="6">Selecta&#355;i una din op&#355;iunile de mai jos:<br/></font>
    <br /><br /><br /><select name="motiv" class="inp2">
    <option class="inp2" value="ridicare produs">Vreau s&#259; ridic un produs</option>
    <option class="inp2" value="predare produs" selected>Vreau s&#259; predau un produs</option>
    <option class="inp2" value="factura storno">Vreau s&#259; ridic factura storno</option>
    <option class="inp2" value="reclamatie">Vreau s&#259; fac o sesizare</option>
    <option class="inp2" value="informatii">Vreau s&#259; adresez o &#238;ntrebare</option>
    </select>
          </td>
        </tr>   
        <tr align="center">  
        <td><br /><br /><br /><input type="submit" name="submit" class="buttons" value="M&#258; &#206;NREGISTREZ"></td> </tr>  
        </table>
</form>
```

input.php code:

```
<? //the example of inserting data with variable from HTML form //input.php

require 'db.php';

$nume = $_POST['nume']; $motiv = $_POST['motiv']; //inserting data order $order = "INSERT INTO flux_receptie            (motiv, nume_client)            VALUES          ('$motiv',          '$nume')";

//declare in the order variable $result = mysql_query($order);  //order executes if($result){    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=index2.php\">"; } else {  echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=www.sss.ro\">"; } ?>
```

If I press submit button, it shows me a blank page with:

; } else { echo ""; } ?>

I am using Wamp web local server. Does anyone know what is the problem? Thank you :)

Comment: The first thing you have to learn in such situations is: take a look into your http servers error log file. Typically that is something like `/var/log/httpd/error.log`, not sure where that file is stored on MS-Windows based systems sorry. That is where php logs errors to. There is absolutely no sense in _guessing_ what might be wrong if you can take a look into that file and read what is wrong.

Comment: I read that php error file. No error found on index.php and input.php.

Comment: It could also be that your http server does not interpret php. Have a try and tell your browser to display the "source code" if that nearly blank page. What is in there?

Comment: Oh, and could you please fix the second code block you posted above? It would assume that your code does not really look like those 4 lines...

Comment: No :)) it looks as it should be in my php.

Comment: I run view-source:http://localhost/input.php from Chrome and revealed all text with green, except: "
;} else { echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=www.sss.ro\">";
}
?>

Comment: "all text"? What text?

Comment: Ah, ok. That clearly means that your http server does not interpret the php code. It delivers it as text. That is a configuration issue usually. If things work right you have no way to see the php code inside your browser.

Comment: Solve it by: Enable short tags. click on wamp icon > PHP > PHP Settings > short open tags. Make sure it is checked. Thanks man!